# patren un-lock of chines andriod tablet (company name: ready) with no volume and home keys (it was in use my nephew locked it)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, tablet

I have a patren locked chines made andriod tablet. I want to unlock it
Note: tablet does not have volume or home keys.
It was a new tablet and was not connected to internet or google account either

Comment: May I know why you mention "no volume and home keys"? Is it because you want to do factory reset since it's locked?

Comment: my tablet has no volume keys and home keys. only one power button which is used as home button

Comment: no dear i was using it. it got locked from my nephew